# How do I receive all children from Firebase realtime db (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Here's the structure of my db. I need to receive all children of each "history/uid" reference (e.g. those marked 8, 9, 0). Is there any way to do this in Flutter?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Firebase comes with documentation on [how to read and write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write), including [reading a list of values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events). I'd also recommend previous [questions about reading a list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%5bflutter%5d%20list&searchOn=3).